# Calculate the height of an element based on the number of rows

Tags: jquery

I have an element that's height is being calculated by its content (a `ul`). At the moment the `ul` has two rows with three items in each. I am setting `.element`s position on screen using the following CSS;

```
.element {
position: absolute;
left: 30px;
top: -139px;
}
```

The markup for this is

```
<div class="element">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the future there will a need to add a third row to the `ul` which means the `top` positioning I am using will hide this new row (as the element div sits on top of another div), which is far from ideal.

I think i'll need to do this with jQuery, so regardless of how many rows get added, I don't need to change the CSS to fix this.

The WIP jQuery I have this far looks like:

```
var elemImgHeight = $('.element li img').height();
var toggles = $('.element li');
var numOfRows = math.ceil( toggles.length() / 3 );
var elemTopOffset = numOfRows * elemImgHeight + 10;

    if ($('.element li') => 7) {
        $('.element').css({ top:elemTopOffset })
    }
```

I'm not sure if I am on the right track with this, so could do with some pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1, could have been quite easier if XSLT would come into picture, anyways let's see what fellow members opinion is ..am curious to know as well.

Comment: $('.element li') => 7   this is a typo, right?

Comment: Really i cannot understand your jquery code with variable names you are using and what you do with it

Comment: Can the `li` or `img` tags be of different width/height?

Comment: @AndersHolmström the `img` and `li` will always be the same height/width

Answer (score 1):

Easy ... let's say you have this html structure:

```
<div class="element">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
        <li><img src="#" />Model</li>
    </ul>
</div>​​​​​​​
```

and you want to calculate the top position so that only the last li element is shown...
using this:

```
var theElement = $(".element");
var topPosition = theElement.find("ul li:last").outerHeight()-theElement.outerHeight();
theElement.css("top",topPosition);
```

a sample is located here: http://jsfiddle.net/senegalo/eEya4/2/

Comment: that get the top position of the last li, but ideally I need to get the position of parent div